# Каким образом реализовать постоянный ввод?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //напишите тут ваш код
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = in.nextInt();
        boolean x = false;
        while (x) {
            if (a != -1) {
                a += a;
                continue;
            } else if (a == -1) {
                System.out.println(-1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно реализовать постоянного ожидания ввода в консоле? до того как будет введено -1?

Comment: видимо поместить `int a = in.nextInt();` в цикл

Comment: но тогда IDE ругается на то что  <a>  не деклалирована

Comment: Спасибо вам, я положил её в цикл. Но перед тем как написать комментарий о том что ругается компилятор. Заведомо удалил boolean x = false;  :)    Очередной раз моя невнимательность меня подвела.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее проверять а не сразу брать значение с сканера

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
             int a = in.nextInt();
             //....
        }
    }
}
```